# Robustness of Quantile Regression

Tags: regression, quantiles, extreme-value, robust, quantile-regression

Is the 99th Quantile Regression model a robust model?
From my understanding, Quantile Regression is supposed to be robust in nature, but removing some outliers using IQR, the results obtained by 99th Quantile Regression Model is significantly different.
So, should we go for removing outliers in case of 99th Quantile Regression? Should we keep some points in mind while removing outliers?

Comment: Whether to remove outliers is a large and vexed question but there are already many threads on that. Look at the most upvoted threads under the tag `outliers`,  In that sense, this is not at all a new question here.

Comment: Yes, removing the extreme values is a horrible idea in this case. But to the point of robustness, quantile regression, like any regression, is certainly *not* robust to violation of the correct functional specification (e.g., linearity) assumption.

Comment: @BigBendRegion  , I wanted advice in this case,  as we are interested in modelling extreme quantiles, does removing extreme cases a good idea? As we end up removing the extreme cases here.

Comment: @NickCox, is removing outliers in case of modelling an extreme quantile a good idea?

Comment: I would say it’s a very bad idea.   You are removing data points you need to do that job.

Answer (score 2):

Of course the results are different if you removed data which the model is going to model, i.e. the extremes. This is not a question about quantile regression but rather about quantiles. The median is very robust and has a breakdown point of 50%, meaning half of the data could be wrong and the median would still work. The 99-th percentile, however, has a breakdown point of 1%, so in this sense it is not robust, not compared to the median, for example.

Comment: This is the point. In short, the answer depends entirely on which quantile you are referring to. Even the median can in some circumstances lacl robustness, as when you have almost as many 0s and 1s in a population and the median of samples jumps between 0 and 1 capriciously.  However, with middle quantiles, quantile regression is often robust, but often not at all with extreme quantiles. You may need very large datasets of high quality to model extreme quantiles well, especially if the focus is on high values in positively skewed distributions.

Comment: *the median would still work* only holds in a certain technical sense which is quite different from how we would interpret this using casual language. After invaliding 50% of the data, the sample median could end up very, very far from the actual sample median. An analogous argument applies for the 99th percentile.

Comment: @RichardHardy That's true, if we were to fetch 50% of the data in the upper portion of the distribution and put it in the 50% lower portion of the distribution we could get very surprising results. I assumed no such shenanigans, but rather more "classical" cases of having extreme values.

Comment: @user2974951, would assuming such a thing not amount to missing the point of the notion of a "breakdown point"? I am not saying we should generally assume the worst case scenario, but a "breakdown point" is *defined* by using exactly that, is it not?